# Create correlated variables in R

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

I am trying to create a dataset where columns 2,3,4 are correlate (0.98,0.97,0.96, respectively) to column 1. Right now I have this code:

```
library(MASS)

X<-mvrnorm(20,mu=c(5,6),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.98,0.98,1),ncol=2),empirical=TRUE)
cor(X)

Y<-mvrnorm(20,mu=c(5,6),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.97,0.97,1),ncol=2),empirical=TRUE)
cor(Y)
Y <- Y[,2]

Z<-mvrnorm(20,mu=c(5,6),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.97,0.97,1),ncol=2),empirical=TRUE)
cor(Z)
Z <- Z[,2]

data <- cbind (X,Y,Z)
cor(data)
```

and it produces this matrix:

```
                                  Y          Z
   1.00000000  0.9800000000 0.0826655886 -0.4293286
   0.98000000  1.0000000000 0.0009559618 -0.5221029
Y  0.08266559  0.0009559618 1.0000000000  0.1847887
Z -0.42932859 -0.5221029358 0.1847886713  1.0000000
```

I would like the final outcome to look like this. It doesn't matter how the column 2,3,4 are correlated with each other (i.e. the X), as long as they have the right correlation with the first column.

```
  1    0.98   0.97   0.96
 0.98    1      X     X
 0.97    X      1     X 
 0.96    X      X     1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since this seems to be generally about creating a random sample with certain statistical properties, it's probably a better discussion to have at [stats.se]. There doesn't seem to be anything in particular that would be R specific (or specific to any programming language) as far as the techniques required to generate such data.